# How to delete multiple objects from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How to delete multiple objects from an array?

Currently I have

```
let arry1 = [
    {
        id:0,
        name:'My App',
        another:'thing',
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'My New App',
        another:'things'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'My New App',
        another:'things'
    }
];
```

Then I have an indexes array like this

```
let arry2 = [1, 2]; // Indexes to delete
```

finally the result has to be:

```
let arry1 = [{
    id:0,
    name:'My App',
    another:'thing',
}]
```

Comment: You can use the ES6 filter array method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: What did you try? Use a `.filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter`. It expects an *predicate* and will return an elemtent if the *predicate* returns `true`. I used `excludes` as *predicate* and it will return `false` if the current `index` is inside the `indicesToRemove`.

```
objects.filter((object, index) => excludesIndicesToRemove(index))
```

```js
const objects = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'My App',
    another: 'thing',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'My New App',
    another: 'things'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'My New App',
    another: 'things'
  }
]

const indicesToRemove = [1, 2]

const not = bool =>
  !bool

const includes = xs => x =>
  xs.includes(x)

const excludes = xs => x =>
  not(includes(xs)(x))

const excludesIndicesToRemove = excludes(indicesToRemove)

console.log(
  objects.filter((object, index) => excludesIndicesToRemove(index))
)
```

Comment: You've mentioned readability, yet you've used 'not' and 'include' and 'remove' all in the same method name. It would be better to use 'exclude' than 'not include', for example. Maybe something like excludeIndices([1,2]) would be more readable.

Comment: Nice, but in FP `not` could be a function as well, `not = f => a => !f(a)` and then you can define `excludes` simply as `xs => not(includes(xs))`

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter with an index variable, so you can keep what you want depending on its index:

```
let arr2 = arr1.filter( (e,i) => i !== 2 && i !== 1);
```

Or specifying the indexes you don't want:

```
let arr2 = arr1.filter( (e,i) => [2,1].indexOf(i) === -1);
```

Answer (score -2):

`filter` is immutable in that it does not modify the original array. If you want to modify `arry1`, use `splice`.

```
arry2.sort((a, b) => b - a).forEach(e => arry1.splice(e, 1))
```

```js
let arry1 = [
    {
        id:0,
        name:'My App',
        another:'thing',
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'My New App',
        another:'things'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'My New App',
        another:'things'
    }
];

let arry2 = [1, 2]; // Indexes to delete

arry2.sort((a, b) => b - a).forEach(e => arry1.splice(e, 1));

console.log(arry1);
```